# How Can One Convert BSD Licensed Software into Protected, Monetizable Software (That's Still Open Source)?

Tags: bsd, monetization

## 1 Context

Suppose **BusinessCorp** finds **SoftwareProductA** online. **SoftwareProductA** is made under a BSD License.  Now **BusinessCorp** wants to monetize **SofwareProductA**, so it makes non-trivial adjustments to **SoftwareProductA** to create **SoftwareProductB**.  The way that **BusinessCorp** wants to make money with **SoftwareProductB** is to distribute it as a free and open source product, but to use it as a platform for other monetary apps (for example, **SoftwareProductB** might be something like the Android OS, with the Android App store being the indirect monetization strategy).

## 2 Problem

Even though **BusinessCorp** wants to distribute **SoftwareProductB** as a free and open-source product, it wants to protect itself from competitors. For example, it wants to prevent other companies from taking **SoftwareProductB**, incrementally changing it into **SoftwareProductC**, and then monetizing it either indirectly as a platform or directly through licensing fees.

## 3 Question

What license can **BusinessCorp** use to best protect **SoftwareProductB** from competitors in this way? Is there a license which allows *only* **BusinessCorp** to monetize **SoftwareProductB**  (either indirectly as a platform or directly through licensing fees) and its derivatives, but to still keep it open-source for hobbyists to tinker with? And how does the original BSD license that **SoftwareProductA** was written under affect all of this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about FLOSS.

Answer (score 2):

> Even though BusinessCorp wants to distribute SoftwareProductB as a free and open-source product, it wants to protect itself from competitors. For example, it wants to prevent other companies from taking SoftwareProductB, incrementally changing it into SoftwareProductC, and then monetizing it either indirectly as a platform or directly through licensing fees.

This is simply a contradiction. Free and open source and not allowing certain users or use cases doesn't mix at all.

Here's a somewhat similar question with the same answer: [Which OpenSource License for a proprietary software?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5329/which-opensource-license-for-a-proprietary-software)

Comment: Then how did i.e. Google Android protect itself from competitors?

Comment: @George they use trademarks to protect the Android mark and commercial contracts.

Comment: The Android Open Source Project can be used by anybody, including Google competitors. Check out the AOSP faq, especially the parts about Android compatibility: http://source.android.com/source/faqs.html. In addition to the already mentioned trademark, you'll need commerically licenced software to access Google Play, and this software is not a part of AOSP.

Comment: [Here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12461099) someone claims that you can do something like I suggested in my original post. Is this wrong?

Comment: @George I don't believe it is wrong, but it's not similar to your suggestion either. You want to determine what the user can and cannot do with the software based on who they are. While I'm sure you can find ways of doing this, you can't do it and at the same time claim that the software is open source.

Comment: Is what I'm trying to do then better termed "Fair Source"?

Comment: No idea. It's not open source and open source is what this site is about.

Comment: In addition Free and Open-Source do not allow a non-commercial clause.